# Didn’t find class … on path: DexPathList in release mode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

We have a relatively small android project (mobile and wear), that we have trouble when it is built in release mode. 
The exception the mobile app throws is:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-766
Process: com.[OURAPP], PID: 9986
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/JsonParser;
    at com.[OURAPP].Login.LoginRefresher$1HttpRefresher.run(LoginRefresher.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.gson.JsonParser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.[OURAPP]-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.[OURAPP].Login.LoginRefresher$1HttpRefresher.run(LoginRefresher.java:134) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonParser
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                              ... 3 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

So something is wrong with the Multidexing. I have looked everywhere for a solution, and I can’t really see what we are doing wrong. We use gradle 2.14, and the build.gradle file for the mobile project looks like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.[OURAPP]"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode buildVersionCode()
        versionName version
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree( include: ['*.jar'],dir: 'libs')
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile project(':common')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':syncservice')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:1.13.+'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:lock-facebook:2.4.+'
    //compile 'com.auth0.android:lock-googleplus:2.0.+'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0' 
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error doesn’t happen when built in debug mode. The error also doesn’t happen if the minSDKVersion is set to 19, but that is not really a fix.

We have

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

In our main application class.

I’m building from the commandline with

```
gradlew clean assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=Release\releaseKeyStore.jks -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=[PASS]-Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias="[OURAPP} android release key" -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=[PASS]”
```

If anyone can tell me how to debug this kind of error that would be a huge help, because I feel that it might be difficult for an outside to tell us what exactly we do wrong, but any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: You have enabled proguard. Are there any rules? Are any suspicious messages, when assembling the release version?

Comment: I can see u have used compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7' in dependencies but can u check do u have gson jar in libs?

Comment: @R.Zagórski how do I check that? My output contains nothing proguard related. And I was under the impression that when "minifyEnabled false" is set proguard wouldn't mess things up. If I enable it on the other hand, it won't run.

Comment: Two remarks: 1. Does you `Application` class extends from `MultiDexApplication`? 2. Try moving `MultiDex.install(this);` to `onCreate` method of `Application` class.

Comment: @R.Zagórski moving it to onCreate doesnt change anything :( - And we don't extend MultiDexApplication.

Comment: So you should extend [`MultiDexApplication`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)`. [Read, what has to be changed in manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Comment: No need to extend MultiDexApplication, since they already calling MultiDex.install(this). @sjkp, I'd start with verifying that the class exists in your release APK file. Use apktool or ClassyShark for that. If it exists, run the application once again and look for any errors/warnings in logs that mention JsonParser. Did you find any of them?

Comment: @AlexLipov that was my understanding too. We will try the tools you mentioned